# How to save Iperf result in an output file

Tags: python, networking, iperf, mininet

I am running iperf between a set of hosts that are read from a txt file, here's how I am running it:

```
h1,h2 = net.getNodeByName(node_id_1, node_id_2)

net.iperf((h1, h2))
```

It runs well and displays the results. But, I want to save the output of iperf result in a separate txt file. Does anyone know how I can apply it on the above code?

Answer (score 2):

Do you already try:

> --output test.log

(in newer versions `--logfile`)

or using

> youriperfexpr > test.log

Comment: Hi Paolo, I tried it as net.iperf((h1, h2)) > test.log and I got an error:
NameError: global name 'test' is not defined

Comment: if you use this command, mininet try to run test.log as one of its CLI command. 
What I used to do is

    h1 <linux command to run in the VM h1> 

In this case it didn't work and I don't know why.

What works for me is

 1. run xterm h1 and xterm h2 in the CLI
 2. iperf -s in h2
 3. iperf -c <h2_ip_address> in h1

That's all!

Comment: Paolo - I am running iperf in mininet (on ubuntu virtual box) that is installed on my macbook.

Comment: user3771522 - It totally make sense. But I do not want to use xterm because my mininet has 24 switches and I want to run iperf for many instances. Like I have a set of server/cleint in a txt file and when I run iperf: it reads the server/client form that txt file and displays the result. Which works fine but for analyzing the output, I would like to save it in a file somewhere.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you.  
 https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2011-August/000487.html

Comment: So I figured using these commands, I can save the result of iperf in a output file:                                      h1.cmd('iperf -s > server_output.txt &')
h2.cmd('iperf -t 5 -c ', h1.IP() + '  >  client_output.txt &')            But the problem is it overwrites the previous results. I have a set of server-client between which I run iperf and want to save the output in a file but the above command overwrites the previous ones and saves the iperf result of only the last server-clinet set. Any idea how to get that fixed in the above commands I am using?

Answer (score 2):

In order to store the results of iperf test in a file , add ***| tee*** followed by the filename.txt to your command line for example :

iperf -c ipaddress -u -t 10 -i 1 | tee result.txt

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well.  Although the manpage specifies "-o" or "--output" to save your output to a file, this does not actually work.

It seems that this was marked as "WontFix":
https://code.google.com/p/iperf/issues/detail?id=24:

> Looks like -o/--output existed in a previous version but in not in the
>   current version.  The consensus in yesterday's meeting was that if
>   --output existed then we should fix it, otherwise people should just use shell redirection and we'll mark this WontFix.  So, WontFix.

So maybe just use typescript or ">test.log" as suggested by [Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648682/paolo)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is given by Chiara Contoli in here: [iperf result in output file](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2014-October/005199.html)

In summary:

```
h1.cmd('iperf -s > server_output.txt &')
h2.cmd('iperf -t 5 -c ', h1.IP() + '  >  client_output.txt &')
```

Answer (score 1):

Server

```
iperf3 -s -p <port> -B <IP> >> <filename> &
```

Client

```
iperf3  -p <port>  -c <server_ip> -B <client_ip> -t 5 >> <filename>
```

Make sure you kill the iperf process on the server when done

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running it on python, another method to save the result is to use popen:

```
popen( '<command> > <filename>', shell=True)
```

For example:

```
popen('iperf -s -u -i 1 > outtest.txt', shell=True)
```

You can check this for further information:

https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Introduction-to-Mininet#popen

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save a file in the txt format.
On the client machine run cmd(adm) and after that you need to write this:

```
cd c:\iperf3
iperf3.exe -c "you server address"  -p "port"  -P 10 -w 32000 -t 0 >> c:\iperf3\text.txt
```

(-t 0) - infinity
On the client machine, you will see a black screen in cmd. It's normal. You will see all the process in the server machine. After your test, on the client machine in cmd need push ctrl+ c and after (y).
Your file in directory `c:\iperf3\text.txt` after that collect all information about this period.
**If you push close in cmd this file `text.txt` will be empty.**

Recommended open this file in NotePad or WordPad for the correct view.